# Minimal polynomial of $2\cos(12^\circ)$ and $2\cos(15^\circ)$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

this problem stumped me a long time ago and I haven't posted it yet, so here it is. I want to find the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$  of  $2\cos(12^\circ)$ and $2\cos(15^\circ)$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 12 degrees is otherwise known as the primitive 30th roots of unity, while 15 degrees is the 24th root. Now, check out this article: http://www.itp.kit.edu/~wl/EISpub/A181875.pdf

Comment: can you explain why the minimal polynomial of 2*cos(12) is a factor of $x^{30}-1$ ?

Comment: @animalcroc Typing too fast, the truth is almost that, but I will correct momentarily.

Comment: @animalcroc OK, look now.